# Know which variables are linear combinations of others from covariance (correlation) matrix

Tags: covariance, linear-algebra

Suppose I have the covariance and correlation matrices for several variables. I know one of the variables is almost a linear combination of the others. Is there any characteristic about the corresponding row in the covariance (correlation) matrix that I can use to pick out this variable?

Comment: The variance inflation factor is in direct relation with it's diagonal corresponding element of the inverse of covariance matrix, if that helps. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_inflation_factor

Comment: Can you get the eigenvalues of the correlation matrix? Is any of the eigenvalues virtually zero?

Comment: @AntoniParellada Yes, that's why I'm sure there is strong collinearity. I just don't know which variables.

Comment: @rapaio Does it mean the largest diagonal entry in the inverse of the covariance matrix correspond to the variables that's most collinear with the others?

Comment: Do you have the design matrix or only its covariance matrix? Why insist on this particular method of collinearity analysis?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have some random variable $Y$ and you want to know the [projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)) of $Y$ onto a series of random variables $X_1, \ldots, X_k$ and a constant 1. This is a linear regression of the random variable $Y$ on random vector $\mathbf{X} = \begin{bmatrix} X_1 \\ X_2 \\ \ldots \\ X_k \end{bmatrix}$ and 1. Can you do that knowing just covariance matrices? Yes!

- Define the [inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space) of random variables $U$ and $V$ as $\langle U, V \rangle = \operatorname{E}[UV]$. Consequently, [covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance) is the inner product of demeaned random variables.
- Let $\Sigma_{\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}} = \operatorname{Cov}\left(  \mathbf{X} \right) = \operatorname{E}[(\mathbf{X} - \operatorname{E}[\mathbf{X}](\mathbf{X} - \operatorname{E}[\mathbf{X}]')$ be the covariance matrix for random vector $\mathbf{X}$.
- Let $\Sigma_{\mathbf{X}Y} = \operatorname{Cov}\left( \mathbf{X}, Y \right) = \operatorname{E}\left[(\mathbf{X} - \operatorname{E}[\mathbf{X}])(Y - \operatorname{E}[Y]) \right] $ be a $k$ by 1 matrix giving the covariance with $X_1$ and $Y$, $X_2$ and $Y$ etc...

Then we can write the orthogonal decomposition:

$$ Y - \operatorname{E}[Y] =  \left( \mathbf{X} - \operatorname{E}[\mathbf{X}] \right) \cdot \mathbf{b} + \epsilon $$
Doing some algebra:

$$ Y = \underbrace{  \left( \operatorname{E}[Y] + \mathbf{b} \cdot \operatorname{E}[\mathbf{X}] \right)}_{\text{intercept}} +    \mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{X} + \underbrace{\epsilon}_{\text{error term}} $$

Where: 
$$\mathbf{b} = \Sigma_{\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}}^{-1} \Sigma_{\mathbf{X}Y}$$

And $\epsilon$ is a random variable orthogonal to the linear span of the random variables $X_1, \ldots, X_k$ and 1. (Note, orthogonality of $\epsilon$ to 1 implies that $\operatorname{E}[\epsilon] = 0$.)

## Example:

Let the covariance matrix of $ \begin{bmatrix} X_1 \\ X_2 \\ Y \end{bmatrix}$ be given by:

$$ \Sigma = \begin{bmatrix}     1.0010  &  0.5005  &  3.5035\\
    0.5005  &  1.2505 &   4.7529\\
    3.5035  &  4.7529 &  22.2675\end{bmatrix} $$

Then 
$$\Sigma_{XX} =  \begin{bmatrix}    1.0010  &  0.5005 \\ 0.5005 &   1.2505 \end{bmatrix} \quad \quad \Sigma_{XY} = \begin{bmatrix} 3.5035\\4.7529 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$ \mathbf{b} = \Sigma_{XX}^{-1} \Sigma_{XY} \approx \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix} $$

And we could write
$$ Y = \alpha + 2X_1 + 3 X_2 + \epsilon$$
where $\alpha$ is a scalar and $\epsilon$ is a mean zero random variable orthogonal to the $X_1$ and $X_2$.

### Maybe you want the null space of your covariance matrix?

From your comment, it sounds like you want to know what vectors [span](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span) the [the null space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(linear_algebra)) of the covariance matrix. For example in MATLAB, you would call `null(Sigma)` where `Sigma` is your covariance matrix.

Computation of the null space is typically done through a [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition).

Let $\mathbf{w}$ be a vector and $\mathbf{X}$ be a random vector.. If $\mathbf{w}$ belongs to the null space of $\Sigma = \operatorname{Cov}(\mathbf{X})$ then:

$$ \Sigma \mathbf{w} = \mathbf{0} $$

Hence $\operatorname{Var}\left(\mathbf{X} \cdot \mathbf{w} \right)  = 0$ and $\mathbf{X} \cdot \mathbf{w} = 0$ almost surely.

Comment: Thanks for answering. My current problem is that some of $X_1, ..., X_k$ are collinear and I want to find out which by using the covariance or correlation matrix for $X_1, ..., X_k$. I can of course do a PCA on them and get rid of the collinearity, but I'm trying to identify the original variables which were the culprit.

Comment: @ZizhengTai Then you want the null space.